# Getting delegate calls from one class to many

Tags: ios, protocols

Maybe I misunderstand the delegate pattern, but can somebody please explain how can I get delegate calls into 2 classes from a single one when I only define one protocol and delegate property?

Running the code below will only call doSomething in the detail2VC, but I want to have the message in both. I can define second property that would conform with the protocol, or define second protocol, but I assume that's not the right approach.

**ViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@protocol ViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>

@optional
- (void)doSomething;

@end

@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, weak) id <ViewControllerDelegate> delegate;

@end
```

**ViewController.m**

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "Detail1VC.h"
#import "Detail2VC.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(doSomething)]) {

        [self.delegate doSomething];
    }
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"d1"]) {

        self.delegate = (Detail1VC *)segue.destinationViewController;
    }

    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"d2"]) {

        self.delegate = (Detail2VC *)segue.destinationViewController;
    }
}

@end
```

**Detail1VC.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface Detail1VC : UIViewController <ViewControllerDelegate>

@end
```

**Detail1VC.m**

```
#import "Detail1VC.h"

@interface Detail1VC ()

@end

@implementation Detail1VC

- (void)doSomething
{
    NSLog(@"detail1 done");
}

@end
```

**Detail2.VC is identical to Detail1.VC**

Comment: Delegation is not the only architecture. Consider NSNotification...

Comment: there is no restriction having more delegates, call them delegate1, delegate2 etc. In Detail1VC set ViewController.delegate1 = self, in Detail2VC set ViewController.delegate2. You will also have to update [self.delegate1 doSomething], [self.delegate2 doSomething]; The delegate it's simply an id pointer to a viewController.

Comment: Yeah, I tried that and it worked. I just thought more classes can subscribe to a single delegate and get messages, but it's not the case. Thanks anyway.

Comment: best way would be NSNotification. otherwise store all the delegates in a NSMUtableArray or LinkedList where each node will contain a delegate. Traverse the linklist or array and call the delegate function on each delegate

Comment: One delegate can point only to one object at a time, indeed notification would be a solution if you want to "broadcast" to several VCs. But also you can do ViewController.delegate = self in ViewDidApear of each destination controler, this might get you where you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the best practice, by using only one delegate and change it dynamically form outside the class who declared the protocol. Code reviewers can hate the way you have `NSArray` of delegates, or can be misleading for other developers if you work with a team. 
The best approach is to use `NSNotification` to notify multiple objects about an event. Keep using the best code, which is familiar to other `objective-c` developers.

Answer (score 3):

Just have a collection of delegates instead of just one. All of them should conform to the same protocol of course.

In your master instance you just have to iterate through your collection (NSSet or NSArray) of delegates and call the method declared in your protocol.

There is no rule that forbids to do that.

Of course you could also think if other patterns would not fit better like observer or why not simply use the NSNotificationCenter.

Nothing is bad just pick up what fits you the best.